# Solr parent-child query

Tags: solr

I am trying to query solr documents based on criteria both in parent **and** a child.

[Documentation: BlockJoinQueryParsers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers) instructs to use a query like:

```
q= +title:join +{!parent which="content_type:parentDocument"}comments:SolrCloud
```

where `title` is a parent's field and `comments` is child's.
A query like this works fine. However, I can not add any other condition on the child. No matter what statement I try to put after the '}', it fails with SyntaxError. For example

```
q= +title:join +{!parent which="content_type:parentDocument"}(comments:SolrCloud AND id:4)
```

fails with SyntaxError.

I think I can use a workaround by utilizing fq parameter, but I wonder if it is possible to achieve in one query.

P.S. I am using Solr 6.6, and upgrading to version 7 can be considered.

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [local parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/local-parameters-in-queries.html#specifying-the-parameter-value-with-the-code-v-code-key), basically your query is equal to

```
q= +title:join +{!parent which="content_type:parentDocument" v='comments:SolrCloud'}
```

which could be rewritten even further:

```
q= +title:join +{!parent which="content_type:parentDocument" v=$qq}&qq=+comments:SolrCloud +whatever:ClauseYouWant
```

Comment: Thanks, v-parameter works, I can supply complex parameter sets. However, "qq" parameter reference still failing with "undefined field" message.

Comment: do you have the field in schema with the name you're trying to get?

Comment: Yes, I have. And notably, even the simplest queries with "qq" fail, while complex ones that utilize "v" parameter directly work Ok.