# Solr : How to retrieve Parent Doc when Both child and parent having the same field name which is used in the search criteria

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to retrieve the Parent Document by using the Block Join Parent Query Parser
(q={!parent which=allParents}someChildren),
but the filter condition i gave for  is having the same field in the parent and the child, So the Parser is throwing the below Error :
"Child query must not match same docs with parent filter. Combine them as must clauses (+) to find a problem doc."

For Ex :

```
{
"parent": {
    "name": "sam",
    "age": "30",
    "degree": "MBBS",
    "docType" : "parent",
    "childrens": [{
            "name": "chang",
            "age": "3"

        },
        {
            "name": "joseph",
            "age": "10"

        }
    ]
}
```

}

I want to trigger a below query :

q={!parent which=docType:parent}name:chang

or

q={!parent which=docType:parent}name:sam

In both the cases i want to retrieve the Parent document, i want to match the name field i am specifying in the  section to the parent name field or to the child name field.

I think it is not possible with the "Block Join Parent Query Parser", Looking for some alternative solution.

Can some one please help with the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to add another condition in `someChildren` to make sure that it's not going to match any parent.

To do so you could add a specific property to the children, for example `"docType" : "child"`, and use it in combination with the `name` one:

```
q={!parent which="docType:parent" v="+docType:child +name:sam"}
```

See also: [Solr parent-child query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686309/solr-parent-child-query)